# How do I set only one element of a one dimensional array using useState in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I want to set the value of an element of an array something like this

```
array_name[2] = true;
```

And also I want to access the value

```
console.log(array_name[2]);
```

But how do I do this using useState hook in react js? Does anyone know? Please tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const [array, setArray] = React.useState([1, 2, 3]);
// ...
setArray(oldArray => {
   const newArray = [...oldArray];
   newArray[2] = true;
   return newArray;
});
```

is the most bulletproof way to do that I can think of. Using the function form of `setState` also avoids a dependency on `array` for effect/callback hooks using it.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I will try it tomorrow morning in office.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState(initialArray);

// later in your code
setMyArray(prev => {
  prev[2] = true;
  return [...prev]; // because you want updated state for anything watching for changes
});
```

Comment: This modifies the old value, then copies it, so now you have two modified versions. Not necessarily a good idea...